# Assign a PHP variable into a javascript variable not working As expected

Tags: javascript, php, session

Hi I am checking my company web sites XSS vulnerability , by adding some script tags to inputs . actually my company site was vulnerable .

```
<script>alert("Xss Attack");</script>
```

This alerts

> Xss Attack

Now I am trying to do more testing to understand it more , now I am trying to get the session id and pass it to some other web site , then I will get the session id and I will gain the user access using that session_id . this is my code to get session_id , I typed this to my input field and submitted the form.

```
<script>var sess_id = "<?php echo session_id(); ?>"; alert(sess_id); </script>;
```

but this only alert `<?php echo session_id(); ?>`

In my php I out put the variable as

```
<td> <?php echo $name;?> </td>
```

**BUT**

In my PHP page if I directly type the code

```
<script>var sess_id = "<?php echo session_id(); ?>"; alert(sess_id); </script>
```

It correctly gets me the session id like `ba6k806tlcbvqs0l39ipcms956`

I think in my 2 nd case it works correctly because it has no wrapping PHP tags.
In the 1 st case It has wrapping PHP tags `<?echo $name;?>` .

So how should i add the session_id to javascript variable sess_id ? , please help . thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you're putting PHP into an external JavaScript file, it will not work. By the time the JavaScript files are served, PHP will have already done it's thing. JavaScript is client-side where PHP is server-side. You need to ise your JavaScript code within the PHP file to get the desired response back.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend printing or showing the session id anywhere in the page. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14093/why-is-passing-the-session-id-as-url-parameter-insecure

Comment: @NoGray Hi i do not want to print or show session id , this is only for testing , i want to get the session id and pass it to another site and get the session id and attack to this website

Comment: If a user submits php code as a form element, the only way that php could be executed on the server side is if the server script ran it through eval() or something equivalent.